# xlrd not working for 1997 - 2003 xls files :

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, xlsx, xls, xlrd

I am trying to open a ".xls" file from an old version of Excel (1997-2003) to copy it in a .csv file. 
The url of the data is :

https://eco2mix.rte-france.com/download/eco2mix/eCO2mix_RTE_Bretagne_Annuel-Definitif_2013.zip

Impossible to open the file (have tried with pandas, xlrd, pyexcel, ...), the only solution I found was to copy past the content into a new excel sheet.

Here is what I try to do :

```
dataframe = pd.read_excel(data_path + file)
```

Here is the error I get :

```
   raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'P\xe9rim\xe8tr'
```

Any idea ?

---

**Update :**

As I was unable to fix this issue using pandas, I simply parsed the files and mapped it to a .csv one. 
Not graceful, but working.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You wrote: "I am trying to open a ".xls" file" - can you show the code? Does not matter if it does not works

Comment: are you sure that the file is not already open when you try to access it?

Comment: Even Microsoft excel is showing the file as corrupted https://imgur.com/a/NVJBDdZ

Comment: Your excel file has the encoding `Unix(lf)` you need to convert that to `windows(crlf)`

Comment: I added the code I used. And yes, the file is closed when I try to open it. But yes, it does say that the file is corrupted when I try to open it manually.